# Destroying model instance does not remove it from views/storage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, marionette

I am using Backbone, Marionette, and [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to persist a list of items. I have a remove button on the `ItemView`s which fires the model's `destroy` method. This removes the model from the collection successfully and fires the remove event.

However, the `CollectionView` does not remove its `ItemView` automatically (as I think? it should), nor does it remove the model from local storage, so on reloading the page, it's back in the list.

Edit:

The model is removed by this method on the view:

```
confirmRemove : function() {
  this._setRemoveState(false);
  this.model.destroy({success: function() { console.log('model destroyed!');}});
  return false;
}
```

The `success` callback does fire.

Comment: Show some code. I suspect you're not correctly removing the model.

Comment: Did you set-up `localStorage` correctly? Are you calling `itemView.remove()` when the destroy event is triggered on the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems:

1. I overwrote the `ItemView`'s `remove` method unintentionally, so it wasn't removed from the DOM.
2. `destroy` only runs its sync actions on models with ids, assuming that only models with ids are persisted to the server. However, while Backbone.localStorage creates internal ids, it does not persist them back to the models, so there was no id property and Backbone skipped removing it from the server.